# Strange lines appearing on mouse hover

Tags: bug, support, status-completed, design

In profile page, under answer section, whenever I hover on the link it shows two lines under the link. It is a bug. I checked some users profile too, showing the same.

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have put in a fix for it on dev. It will be on live site(both main and meta) after the next production build.

Comment: Cheers, how come you don't have a diamond here??

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm a Stack Exchange employee, not a moderator on this site.

Comment: I know, Jin, but SE employees usually get a diamond where they need e.g. to add moderator only tags. I see you can add those tags, but it's confusing to unaware user.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I see. I believe at some point we removed the diamond from employees and give them limited mod privileges. It was actually confusing for new users to see a person with a diamond that's not a moderator on the site.

Comment: Fair enough, not my place to argue about those decisions but in my opinion it's equally confusing to see what appears to be ordinary user doing moderator only actions like adding red tags. I've even [reported this once](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/154882/152859), lol! :)